# Exception Unhandled error when client stops running

Tags: c#, string, exception, tcp, client-server

The Client is successfully sending string data to the Server via a TCP connection. When the client is stopped or closed, the Server code exits with an 'Exception Unhandled' error at the `string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();` line in the code below.
.

What changes or methods can I use to have the server code gracefully exit the connection and program?

```
   static void Listeners()
        {

            Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client:"+socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint+" now connected to server.");
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =  new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =     new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);

                while (true)
                {
                    string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Message recieved by client:" + theString);
                    break;
                }
                streamReader.Close();
                networkStream.Close();
                streamWriter.Close();

            }
            socketForClient.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit from server program");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: You should use [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for your streams

Comment: That was implemented in the answer below, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
try {
    while (true)
    {
        string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Message recieved by client:" + theString);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

As someone else mentioned, you should use `using` statements to help you with your Disposables:

```
    static void Listeners()
    {
        using (Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket())
        {
            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client:" + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " now connected to server.");
                using (NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient))
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream))
                using (System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Message recieved by client:" + theString);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit from server program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```